# AngularJS component require: componentOne OR componentTwo

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-components

I want to pass some functions in my template to the current active parent component:

```
<div ng-click="thisComponent.parentComponent.fn()"></div>
```

The parent component depends on the page and configuration you are viewing, so I tried:

```
app.component('thisComponent', {
    controllerAs: 'thisComponent'
    require: {
        parentComponent : '?^componentOne' || '?^componentTwo'
    },
    controller: function() {
        this.$onInit = () => {
            // Returns null when the parent is componentTwo
            console.log(this.parentComponent);
        }
    }
});
```

The code doesn't break, it actually works when `componentOne` is the parent, but when it's not, `this.parentComponent` evaluates to `null`, without trying `componentTwo`.

---

**Update 2018-02-28**

Got it working with @Korte's answer (see below), but still wondering why the code above does not work. How come it does not evaluate the next option when the first returns `null`? Anyone care to explain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could require both parent components, then check which one is defined.

e.g.

```
app.component('thisComponent', {
    controllerAs: 'thisComponent',
    require: {
        firstParent : '?^componentOne',
        secondParent: '?^componentTwo'
    },
    controller: function() {
        this.$onInit = () => {
            this.parentComponent = this.firstParent || this.secondParent;
            console.log(this.parentComponent);
        }
    }
});
```

[Here's a working fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/6sg36c6e/10/)

Comment: Of course! Sometimes, things aren't as complicated as you think they are.. Thanks!